# Credential Providers V2 - Add code after submit and check user's password

Tags: c++, credential-providers, winlogon, windows-credential-provider

How do I add my code after click submit button and check user password?

I add my code in GetSerialization function after successfully calling KerbInteractiveUnlockLogonPack and RetrieveNegotiateAuthPackage. But in this state first run my code and later check user password.

I want to first check user password and if that correct then run my code. How do I do?

```
if (_fIsLocalUser)
{
    PWSTR pwzProtectedPassword;
    hr = ProtectIfNecessaryAndCopyPassword(_rgFieldStrings[SFI_PASSWORD], _cpus, &pwzProtectedPassword);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        PWSTR pszDomain;
        PWSTR pszUsername;
        hr = SplitDomainAndUsername(_pszQualifiedUserName, &pszDomain, &pszUsername);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            KERB_INTERACTIVE_UNLOCK_LOGON kiul;
            hr = KerbInteractiveUnlockLogonInit(pszDomain, pszUsername, pwzProtectedPassword, _cpus, &kiul);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                // We use KERB_INTERACTIVE_UNLOCK_LOGON in both unlock and logon scenarios.  It contains a
                // KERB_INTERACTIVE_LOGON to hold the creds plus a LUID that is filled in for us by Winlogon
                // as necessary.
                hr = KerbInteractiveUnlockLogonPack(kiul, &pcpcs->rgbSerialization, &pcpcs->cbSerialization);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    ULONG ulAuthPackage;
                    hr = RetrieveNegotiateAuthPackage(&ulAuthPackage);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        pcpcs->ulAuthenticationPackage = ulAuthPackage;
                        pcpcs->clsidCredentialProvider = CLSID_CSample;
                        // At this point the credential has created the serialized credential used for logon
                        // By setting this to CPGSR_RETURN_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED we are letting logonUI know
                        // that we have all the information we need and it should attempt to submit the
                        // serialized credential.
                        *pcpgsr = CPGSR_RETURN_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED;
                    }
                }
            }
            CoTaskMemFree(pszDomain);
            CoTaskMemFree(pszUsername);
        }
        CoTaskMemFree(pwzProtectedPassword);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the following line in my code to check username/password pair:

```
    bRet = LogonUserExA(lpszUsername, NULL, lpszPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, 
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

`lpszUsername` us the full UPN in one of forms `domain\user` or `user@domain`.
The key constant is `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK`:

> This logon type is intended for high performance servers to
>   authenticate plaintext passwords. The **LogonUserEx** function does not
>   cache credentials for this logon type.

See MS [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) for details on parameters and constant values and also check the remarks section.

In your case it can looks like this:

```
if(LogonUserEx(_pszQualifiedUserName, NULL, _rgFieldStrings[SFI_PASSWORD],
    LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I customize and use from credential providers sample code from Microsoft.